# Using RenderImage does not make Image editable in Experience Editor

Tags: orm, sitecore, glass-mapper, experience-editor

We use Glass Mapper as an ORM for our MVC Sitecore solution. Sample code used to render an image is below.

```
RenderImage(item, x => x.Image, new { la = "", @class = "img-circle", alt = item.Image.Alt }, isEditable: true)
```

Image renders fine, however using this code, I'm unable to edit that image in the Experience Editor. Did anyone face a similar issue? Does anybody have a solution for it?

Comment: Most probably you have some other issues with your html and Sitecore is not able to create html markup required by Experience Editor. Post the code of the whole component and output of the html.

Comment: try Editable(item, x => x.Image, new { la = "", @class = "img-circle", alt = item.Image.Alt })

Comment: Hello Everyone, the code works as expected. My Site is UI responsive, to support different browsers across different OS and device platforms, the design team has applied some styling to the parent div's of the images which makes these images unselectable in experience editor. So from sitecore, glassmapper's end this isnt an issue